# Set custom placeholder in lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I have a form in Lightning Components written using lightning:recordEditForm. Inside that form I have lightning:inputField which is a lookup. Is it possible to set a custom placeholder in this input?

EDIT:
My lookup field is to object Employee. Therefore, the placeholder generated automatically is 'Search Employee'. I'm wondering if this is possible to change this placeholder.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of more detail, as what do you mean by custom placeholder?

Comment: @JayantDas yes, I edited my post

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that you can use a custom placeholder. Even though this component is derived from input tag which has a placeholder attribute, but using that on the inputField has no effect. I am not sure and not a css expert, if there's a way to do so using some custom css which can render the placeholder text.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you **cannot** provide a custom `placeholder` text in lookup fields while using `lightning:inputField`.

Even though the component is rendered as an `input type=text` with a `placeholder` attribute you can't override the attribute.

As an example, if I provide something as below:

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" aura:id="aId"/>
```

I can see this rendered as below (removed other attributes) with the `placeholder` attribute in there:

```
<input id="input-4" type="text" placeholder="Search Accounts..." class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-input-has-icon_group-right">
```

However if I provide the `placeholder` attribute something as below (the compiler does not complain), but it never works and that the `placeholder` attribute always had "*Search Accounts...*" in there and was never overridden.

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" aura:id="aId" placeholder="My Text"/>
```