# How to change placeholder of lightning:inputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, inputfield

I made look up search with lightning:inputField.

search is available, but I want to change its placeholder.

[image: look up search field]

I mean that I want to set some text instead of '001'.

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="SAMPLEOBJECT__c" value="{!v.SearchResult}" aura:id="lookup"/>
```

I tried  `component.find('lookup').get("v.value")` and `component.get("v.SearchResult")`, but both of these returns id of items.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible to change the text of placeholder. @jayanta Das has answered here why you can't: [Set custom placeholder in lightning:recordEditForm](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229232/set-custom-placeholder-in-lightningrecordeditform)

Apart from that, I tried changing it using CSS. But it seems it allows me to change the style of placeholder text but the text itself.

```
.THIS ::placeholder {
    color:red;
    content:'replacement string';
}
.THIS :placeholder-shown{
    content:'replacement string';
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to change the placeholder of "search result",  but not "search field".
But it seems difficult…

Comment: I was trying to use design token overrides, this is much much easier.  Thank you!